# svg <use> not including the style

Tags: html, svg

I have an svg defined as "header.svg" which has styling as well.
Now I want use  this svg in my html like this:

```
<svg class="hamburger" ><use xlink:href="images/header.svg#hamburger" /></svg>
```

I get the image but its black. The styling in header.svg is not included. Why is that?

Comment: Note that referencing another file in SVG `<use>` [does not work in IE<=11](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/).

Comment: Well its working in chrome. I get the image but without style.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423312

Answer (score 0):

No, since styles don't apply across document boundaries.

However, since you can use <object> tag to insert the stylesheet into the svg document using script.

Something like this, and note that this code assumes that the  has loaded fully:

```
var svgDoc = yourObjectElement.contentDocument;
var styleElement = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "style");
styleElement.textContent = "svg { fill: #fff }"; // add whatever you need here
svgDoc.getElementById("where-to-insert").appendChild(styleElement);
```

Of course you can directly link to the stylesheet from the svg file too, without doing any scripting. Either of the following should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  ... rest of document here ...
</svg>
```